# Will DateDiff (or subtracting dates in .NET) execute faster if the dates are closer together?

Tags: .net, sql, date

**Thoughts:**

I imagine that in .NET, the underlying math with dates is done with Ticks.  If that were the case, I would think it wouldn't matter how far away two dates are when determining the difference between them.  You would simply subtract the Ticks and then do a series of divisions to convert the result from Ticks to days.  I don't see how two closer dates would make that faster, or how further dates would slow it down. Am I missing something?

On the SQL side......I have no idea. I imagine it is similar, but I have no proof of it.

**Example/Context:**

Let's say I have a function that if given a start date, end date, and time period (in days for this example), it will tell me how many times that period can occur in the given date range.

```
somefunction(<first of this year>, <first of last year>, <30 days>)
//returns 12
```

One (bad) way to implement this function is to start at the start date, then keep adding the time period (e.g. 30 days) and check to see if you have passed your end date.  However, this gets slower the wider your date range is.

Another way is to figure out how many days are in the date range and divide by the number of days in your time period. In .NET, you can subtract the start and end dates and get a `TimeSpan` back.  In SQL, you can use the `DateDiff` function to do just about the same thing.

My question is if these other methods suffer from the same problem as the first.   Specifically: **Would it be faster to calculate the difference between two dates  that are close or does it make no difference at all?**

**Edit:  Why did I ask this?**

Was the performance for finding the difference between two dates really a problem I ran into?

Yes (with an asterisk). In one of our apps, a calculation was being made that took .3 seconds (and usually had to be made 30 times or so).  The users were less than thrilled, so I tried to see where we could speed things up.  I traced the problem to a function whose purpose was to find the difference between two dates.  Rather than just subtracting them, it iterated over all the dates between start and end, and kept a running total...really.  While switching the function over to just using subtraction (and date diff in SQL (there was similar code in the database)) I saw that there were processes that ran every night to generate a number closer to today for the calculation to use.  I asked this question to see if there was any value in continuing to let those processes run, and use the value they generate, or just use the original start date.  I now feel very comfortable putting those processes to rest.  Thank you all for your answers.

Comment: Are date differential calculations a measured bottleneck in your code?

Comment: @Anthony Believe it or not, yes. There was a far more complicated version of the example function listed and the current implementation was the first (bad) way.  I changed the logic to use date differentials, but there is a lot of infrastructure in place to make the first method more...performant. I was hoping I could clean a lot of it out, but wanted to make absolutely sure there is no need for it anymore.

Comment: @diceguyd30: If the bottleneck is in the .NET code, I'd be *really* interested in hearing more about what you're doing, and how Noda Time does with it. Ping me (or the Noda Time mailing list) if you'd be interested in working together on this.

Comment: @JonSkeet I would be more willing to say that the bottleneck was a poorly designed function.  Now that I've switched the logic to use the second method I listed, it is working wonderfully, and after being (rightfully) chided for my obvious question, I have peace of mind that I won't run into any performance problems with this logic in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answering the general question**

For non-uniform time periods such as months, there may be a certain amount of guesswork involved. In [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) we do some calculations by getting to "a reasonable guess" by (say) dividing a duration in ticks by "the average number of ticks per month", then using the rest of the code to try that guess and see whether it was correct or not. If it wasn't, we adjust the guess and try again.

Now it's *possible* that those guesses will become gradually less accurate over greater time spans - because the "average number of ticks per month" may not be exact. However, I suspect it would have to be over a very large time period to make a significant difference. It's more likely that the guess will be out by one or two due to boundary conditions on the months (e.g. being just the wrong side of a long month) - and that can happen anywhere.

Also note that some calendar systems are more amenable to optimizations than others - and some of these may well be affected by the dates in question. For example, if you have a split Julian/Gregorian calendar with a cutover point, I can easily imagine it taking longer to work out periods between two dates which straddle the cutover than periods which lie entirely one side or the other.

Basically, calendaring systems are complicated - it's best not to assume anything about "it should simply be a matter of XYZ..." as it's almost bound to be wrong :)

**Answering the specific question**

Yes, your second approach sounds like it should indeed be much, much faster than the first for long time periods - and any difference in calculation speed for long and short time periods is unlikely to cause *that* much difference even if it exists; I doubt you'll be able to see it, although it's still worth testing of course.

Answer (score 2):

Any reasonable platform will represent time as some number of units since a certain epoch. In this case, date difference is merely subtraction. Consequently, the performance of this operation is independent of how far apart the operands are. This is true for the CLR and SQL Server.

Why does it matter?

Comment: There was a function needlessly doing a lot of date calculations (several hundred walks over several years with a very small time period several times).  I changed it to use date differences instead, but we had a lot of legacy infrastructure whose job was to try and narrow down the dates the function was walking over.  Before I removed that infrastructure, I wanted to be sure there was no reason to keep it around.

Comment: That assumes you're talking about "units" with a constant length. How long is a month, exactly? (The example used days, but it's not always the case.)

Answer (score 1):

It makes no difference at all for all current programming languages, runtimes/platforms, and database engines (whatever is appropriate.)